# Как загрузить сервер на PythonAnyWhere?

Tags: python, сервер, сокет

мне нужно загрузить сервер, написанный на Python - socket, и мне нужно чтобы он обратился к домену, PythonAnyWhere выдает временный домен для веб-приложений (django, flask и т.д.), но мне нужно просто под сокет, как это можно сделать?

Я пробовал его запускать через консоль(на PythonAnyWhere), но я не получаю доступ к домену или айпи

Comment: Судя по этому обсуждению, это не возможно: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/14884/ . Как вариант, можно написать веб-приложение на вебсокетах (а не на голых TCP сокетах), но это от вашей задачи зависит.

Comment: Спасибо, но я прочитал в PythonAnyWhere вроде даже веб сокеты нельзя ставить, я готов хоть полностью изменить код, но запустить сервер как можно быстрее

Comment: Если так, тогда проще использовать какой-нибудь другой сервис, можно даже платный, типа яндекс облака или selectel.